# How to use slack scope to include email and avatar

Tags: node.js, passport.js, slack-api

Afternoon, looking for a way to retrieve a users email address and their avatar image with passport-slack. The below code I believe just gets the basic information. When I console.log the profile I get username, id, team, provider and display name. I am wondering how I can easily add in also getting their email and avatar. Have not found any useful examples or ones that I can seem to grasp. The below code was actually from a video I found for oauth with Google and I just switched it over to slack.

```
// Configure the Slack Strategy
passport.use(
  new SlackStrategy({
    callbackURL: "/auth/slack/redirect",
    clientID: keys.slack.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.slack.clientSecret,
    scope: ['identity.basic', 'identity.email', 'identity.avatar']
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);
    // Check if user already exist in DB
    User.findOne({username: profile.displayName}).then((currentUser) => {
      if(currentUser){
        // already have the user
        // console.log('User is', currentUser);
        done(null, currentUser);
      } else {
        // If not, create new user in DB
        new User({
          username: profile.displayName,
          slackid: profile.id
        }).save().then((newUser) => {
          // console.log("new user created: " + newUser);
          done(null, newUser);
        });
      }
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

So looks like the code was fine but in order to request the avatar and email from a user I had to add it from the slack API website. Once signed in, you go to Oauth and Permissions and scroll down to the select permission scopes section. There is a drop down of scopes you can add to the list. For me I also had to include indenttity.basic in order to use the avatar and email scope......good times.